# CakePHP, .htaccess and subdomain not working together

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, subdomain

I have the following directory tree in public_html folder:

/app
/test
/cake
...

/app if the Application folder for my site and /test is a subdomain.

The problem is that I've changed the .htaccess, my site is working but the subdomain is returning a 500 error.

My .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?yourdomain.com$
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?yourdomain.com$
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the RewriteCond below to prevent an infinite internal redirect, which could result in a 500 error

```
#skip processing existing files e.g css. png etc
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
#if not already /app/webroot to prevent infinite internal redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app/webroot/ [NC] 
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score -3):

500 error usually means something is wrong with the code, like a missing ; in your model, view or controller. Try double-checking that?